# skipping nines in counter object, AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

It's not that noticeable at first, but my counter skips over to zero and ignores the nines.
 **How can I get my counter to not skipping the nines?**

**Display Object**
It's a column descending from 0-9. 'The object and the values appear correct except the skip'

**my FLA**

```
import flash.display.Sprite; 
import flash.events.Event; 
import flash.utils.Timer; 
import flash.events.TimerEvent; 

var timer:Timer; 
var count:int = 0; 
var fcount:int = 0; 
var numbers:NumbersView; 

trace("-----new NumberDocument created");
timer = new Timer(10); 
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, incrementCounter);     
timer.start();    
numbers = new NumbersView(); 
addChild(numbers); 

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
//addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, traceMeOut);


function incrementCounter(event:TimerEvent) 
{     
    count++;     
    fcount=int(count*count/1000); 
} 

function formatCount(i:int):String 
{    
    return ("000000000" + i).substr(-9, 9); 
} 

function enterFrameHandler(e:Event):void  
{ 
    numbers.setTime(formatCount(fcount)); 
} 
function traceMeOut()
{
    trace("-----Im here on stage!");
}
```

**NumbersView.as**

```
//NumbersView.as - Your Document Class 
package { 

    import flash.display.MovieClip; 

    public class NumbersView extends MovieClip { 

        private var _listItems:Array;  
        private const numHeight:int = 120;  

        public function NumbersView()   
        {  
            _listItems = new Array(); 

            var item:NumberImage;  
            for (var i:Number = 0; i < 9; i++) {  
                item = new NumberImage();  
                addChild(item);  
                item.x = i * item.width;  
                _listItems.push(item);  
            } 

            setTime('123456789'); 

        } 

        public function setTime($number:String):void {  
            var nums:Array = $number.split("");  
            trace(nums); 

            for (var i:Number = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {  

                _listItems[i].start( int(nums[i]) ); 

            }  

        }  


    } 
}
```

**Variation of NumbersView.as** with Tweener

```
//...SNIPPET
public function setTime($number:String):void { 
        var nums:Array = $number.split(""); 
        for (var i:Number = 0; i < nums.length; i++) { 
            if (nums[i] == previousNums[i]) continue; 
            Tweener.removeTweens(_listItems[i]);    

            var nuNum:int = int(nums[i]);
            var nuY:int = nuNum == 0 ? 0 : (nuNum - 1) * -numHeight;

            trace("nuY = " + nuY);
            trace("cY = " + _listItems[i].y);

            Tweener.addTween(_listItems[i], { y:nuY, time:0 } );
        } 
        previousNums = nums; 
    }
```

**Variation of NumbersView.as** that doesn't skip 9, but resets from bottom every count

```
    //...SNIPPET 
    public function setTime($number:String):void { 
        var nums:Array = $number.split(""); 

        for (var i:Number = 0; i < nums.length; i++) { 
        if (nums[i] == previousNums[i]) continue; 
            Tweener.removeTweens(_listItems[i]); 

        var newY:int = int(nums[i]) * -numHeight; 
        if (_listItems[i].y < 0) _listItems[i].y = numHeight; 
            Tweener.addTween(_listItems[i], { y:newY, time:3 } ); 
        } 
        previousNums = nums; 
    }
```

---

**PUBLIC CLASS** extends MovieClip
place 'NumbersView.as' in same directory

**CLASS**
Library/'right-click' Properties/Class:NumberImage

**SYMBOL**
number column 70x1080
numbers 70x120

**TWEENER**
caurina folder in local directory

Comment: I would seriously ditch that code, it's awful. Did you get it from a book? It's impossible to understand, and has you coming back after every question you get answered when the next problem with it comes up. The solution I gave you before was far simpler, and worked flawlessly. I don't see why you don't want to use something more concise, easier to debug, and clearly less flawed.

Comment: NumbersView.as is problematic. I hate to beat a dead horse with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm struggling to follow your code and work out exactly what you mean, so this is a bit of a guess.

In NumbersView.as should

```
(var i:Number = 0; i < 9; i++)
```

be:

```
(var i:Number = 0; i <= 9; i++)
```

The first will go through numbers 0 to 8 and the altered will go through numbers 0 to 9.

However I may have missed the point you were trying to explain.

Comment: a5 is different from a=5 too, see how it makes difference? :)

Comment: Probably right about the loop having to be 'less or equal', but I'm still stuck.

Comment: Looks like this helped and you figured out the rest. Glad you sorted it.

Answer (score 0):

SKIPPING 9 SOLUTION
a. **Tweening set too high** 'I set mine to .05, rather than three'
b. **Number = 0; i <= 9; i++** 'good advice from Richard'
c. **Change number values to integers** var numnum:int = 0;//number

I had some values that were rational, so I changed it from 'Number' to 'int' and it worked.